# OpenAPI: mix of mandatory fields, optional fields and unspecified fields

Tags: swagger, openapi

I need to specify that my endpoint has a mandatory field, an optional field and open to any number of fields(which can be sent without validation).

For e.g. for an endpoint `/user`

```
user_id: str, mandatory
timestamp_utc: timestamp, optional
..*accept_any_extra_fields**..
```

So if someone sends the following json to my endpoint, the endpoint should accept it

```
{ "user_id": 1,
  "name": "Sam",
  "location": "USA"
}
```

but it fails if the following json is sent as it does not contain `user_id`.

```
{ "name": "Sam",
  "location": "USA"
}
```

it should fail.

I'm new to OpenAPI/Swagger. I know I can send the extra data. But how do I describe this as documentation on OpenAPI so a person(or a program) knows that they can send any field (e.g. name, location) along with `user_id`

Comment: OpenAPI 2.0 or 3.0? Are the names of the extra fields predefined or are they arbitrary user-defined fields?

Comment: @Helen. OpenAPI 3.0. They are arbitrary user-defined fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `additionalProperties` keyword allows a schema to have extra properties besides those listed in the `properties` section.

```yaml
MyModel:
  type: object
  required:
    - user_id
  properties:
    user_id:
      type: string
    timestamp_utc:
      type: string
  additionalProperties: true   # OpenAPI 3.x
  # or
  # additionalProperties: {}   # OpenAPI 2.0
```

Actually OpenAPI schemas are [open to extension by default](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/715), in the absence of the `additionalProperties` keyword. However, some tools consider the absence of `additionalProperties` as "additional properties NOT allowed", so it's best to add `additionalProperties: true` / `additionalProperties: {}` explicitly just in case.

If the extra properties are limited to a specific data type, e.g. `string`, use

```yaml
 additionalProperties:
   type: string
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about restricting it to a specific datatype!

Answer (score 2):

Do you use Java-Spring? I use Swagger in Annotation approach in my Spring controllers, and in java code, you can specify params that you need in this way:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get user", notes = "Get a user by the given filters")
@GetMapping("v1/users")
public UserDTO getUsers(@ApiParam(value = "User id", required = true)
                        @RequestParam(value = "user_id", required = true) String userId,

                        @ApiParam(value = "Date", required = false)
                        @RequestParam(value = "timestamp_utc", required = false) 
                        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime utc,

                        @ApiParam(value = "Some other", required = false)
                        @RequestParam(value = "some_other", required = false) String someOther){

             return service.getUser(userId, utc, someOther);
      }
```

The annotation  @ApiOperation is to describre your endpint.

The annotation @ApiParam is to describe the param characteristics, and the attribute required is to inform that is.

Don't forget to add the swagger dependencies, [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.9.2) is on maven.

You also have the possibility to generate your API documentation in YAML. An example is [here](https://editor.swagger.io/) . Please check the endpoint for user/login.

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: I use Python :(. Thank you for your answer though! I'll still check the YAML.